# How could I prepare Iron(III) arsenate (FeAsO4)?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I have no idea in which conditions this compound is formed and would like to find out any / different ways it can be prepared (any easy way not requiring expensive equipment would be great).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iron(III) arsenate or more commonly Ferric orthoarsenate is normally found in nature in the form of a mineral called [Scorodite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scorodite).

It can also be prepared chemically. [From here](http://iron.atomistry.com/ferric_ortho_arsenate.html):

> The monohydrate, $\ce{FeAsO4.H2O}$, is precipitated from solution. The
>   salt, when dried in air, is a dull white insoluble substance,
>   containing one molecule of water. When heated at 100° C. it becomes
>   anhydrous. On treatment with sodium hydrogen carbonate solution, both
>   the monohydrate and the anhydrous salt cause effervescence to take
>   place, a soluble double arsenate being produced. It would appear,
>   therefore, that the hydrated salt is acidic, and determinations of its
>   basicity indicate that its formula is $\ce{FeO.AsO2(OH)2}$.
>
> Colloidal ferric arsenate is prepared by the action of ammonium
>   hydroxide on the insoluble salt.